# Gps status enabled/disabled broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I m trying to register a broadcast receiver to receive updates when gps status is changed.

However, my GpsChangeReceiver onReceive method doesn't seem to be called when gps status is  changed from enabled to disabled or vice-versa.

First of all, i'm registering the reciever:

```
GpsChangeReceiver m_gpsChangeReceiver = new GpsChangeReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(m_gpsChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

Then, I have my GPS Receiver

```
public class GpsChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    if (manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, my manifest contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Can anyone see why the gps receiver is never called when I modify its status from the phone's settings??

Answer (score 20):

There are **two ways** of registering broadcast receivers in Android:

1. in the code (your case)
2. in AndroidManifest.xml

Let me explain the differences.

### Case 1 (Broadcast Receiver registered in the code)

You will only receive broadcasts as long as **context** where you registered your receiver is **alive**.
So when **activity** or **application** is **killed** *(depending where you registered your receiver)* you **won't receive** broadcasts anymore.

I guess you registered broadcast receiver in the **activity context** which is not very good approach.
If you want to register broadcast receiver for your **application context** you can do something like this:

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(m_gpsChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

### Case 2 (Broadcast Receiver registered in AndroidManifest.xml)

You **will receive broadcasts** even when your application is **killed** *(system will wake your application up*). This is right approach when you want to receive broadcasts **no matter** if your app is **running**.

Add this receiver to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.NameOfYourBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**EDIT:**
Some special broadcasts *(i.e. SCREEN_ON or SCREEN_OFF)* must be registered in code *(case 1)* otherwise they won't be delivered to your application.

Comment: available from API 9+

Comment: @steve.mit do I need to declare a permission for case #1? Does the answer to the question apply to any receiver that is registered programatically (bluetooth, wifi) only for the on/off not to actually access the hardware itself?